# How to correctly use two DatePickerSingle in a Dash Application

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Hope you all doing well.

I have two **DatePickerSingle**  that I want to integer in a dash application to use them as a filter further. The problem is that my Dash app only returns values of the first DatePickerSingle, but not the second one ..

```
from datetime import date
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

Min_d =datetime.strptime(str(df_sub['From'].min()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Max_d = datetime.strptime(str(df_sub['From'].max()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2("Date for the First period"),
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='my-date-picker-range',
    min_date_allowed = date(2021,4,1),
    max_date_allowed = date(2021,9,30)
    ),
    
    html.H2("Date for the Second period"),
    
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='my-date-picker-range2',
    min_date_allowed = date(2021,4,1),
    max_date_allowed = date(2021,9,30)
    ),
    
    
    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-range')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('output-container-date-picker-range', 'children'),
    
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date'),
    Input('my-date-picker-range2', 'start_date2'),
    Input('my-date-picker-range2', 'end_date2')
)

def update_output(start_date , end_date , start_date2 , end_date2):
    
        return ( str(start_date) + '   ' + str(end_date)+ '   ' +str(start_date2)+ '   ' +  str(end_date2))  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Here is what I got when I run the app : [image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with these lines:

```
Input('my-date-picker-range2', 'start_date2'),
Input('my-date-picker-range2', 'end_date2')
```

`start_date2` and `end_date2` are not valid properties of `dcc.DatePickerRange`, so change these instances to `start_date` and `end_date`.

Comment: Hey Bas van der Linden, Thank you for your answer , it worked finnaly. Thanks a lot